# How do I make a checkbox that can show password?

Tags: php, html

Here i was just wanted to make a checkbox that shows a password instead of dots. Here is my code.

````html
```
<html>
  <head>
<title>Calvin's Personal Diary and Notes</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
<h3>what's the magic word???</h3>
<form method="post" action="/diary/diary.php">
  <input type="password" name="RandomPassword" placeholder="password">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Enter?">
</form>
<br> <br>
<a href="/diary/password.html">i don't know the password</a>
  </body>
</html>
```
````

Now the problem is how to put the Show password checkbox that can show the password instead of dots?

Comment: you cant use type="text" instead of type="password" ?

Comment: @JohnDoe because it's a password and passwords should be like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
   function myfunction(){
            var show = document.getElementById('show');
            if (show.type== 'password'){
                show.type='text';
            }
            else{
                show.type='password';
            }
        }
```

```html
    <div class="box">
        <label for="">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="" id="show"> <br>
        <label for="">Show Password</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="" onclick="myfunction()"id="">
 
    </div>
```

Comment: It isn't a bad question at all. Some people here at Stackoverflow can be really judgy when they don't like the question. I do not know why stackoverflow condones that kind of behavior. Here's an upvote to negate that negative.

Comment: Because there is answer available to this question. Stackoverflow clearly mentions that at first research your question in googlen in github, in stackoverflow anywhere. Only if you don't find answers than come to stackoverflow. This is such a normal question there should be many answers of it. Stackoverflow is so nice and understable for third user because it's so restrict about the repetition, grammar, proper code issue etc. @Glitch

Comment: The issue is with stackoverflow mods assuming everyone has the right keywords or ability to search through a haystack for a needle at their disposal to be able to find the question or figure out the answer. Not everyone starts out as an expert. Or do you want new people to not join Stackoverflow? If that's the case, the ruleset here is doing an amazing job.

Comment: Instead of negatively voting on the question, redirect the user to the already existing question, leave a comment so they know which answer you want them to see, and finally close/flag the question. That would be the correct approach to doing your job as a contributor, or a mod.